# How do I add up BigDecimals contained in a HashMap with Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, bigdecimal

What is the easiest way to add to a BigDecimal contained in a HashMap in Java 8?

Comment: This could use some elaboration.  "contained in a HashMap" is vague, and does not distinguish between BigDecimal keys and BigDecimal values.  Based on your own answer to your question, it appears you meant to ask how to accumulate BigDecimal map values by key.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've never used `BigDecimal` as a key before so, yes, I meant BDs stored as a value. Plus, why would you ever want to "add to" a `BigDecimal` that is stored as a key?? Keys tend to need to remain the same...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to Java 8, it would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, BigDecimal> bd_map = new HashMap<>();
    bd_map.put("Shirts", BigDecimal.ZERO);
    bd_map.put("Hats", BigDecimal.ZERO);
    bd_map.put("Shoes", BigDecimal.ZERO);

    bd_map.put("Shirts", bd_map.get("Shirts").add(new BigDecimal("5.99")));
    bd_map.put("Shirts", bd_map.get("Shirts").add(new BigDecimal("4.50")));
    bd_map.put("Shoes", bd_map.get("Shoes").add(new BigDecimal("15.99")));
    bd_map.put("Hats", bd_map.get("Hats").add(new BigDecimal("8.00")));
    bd_map.put("Shirts", bd_map.get("Shirts").add(new BigDecimal("8.99")));
    bd_map.put("Shoes", bd_map.get("Shoes").add(new BigDecimal("22.00")));
    bd_map.put("Hats", bd_map.get("Hats").add(new BigDecimal("7.00")));

    System.out.println("Shirts: " + bd_map.get("Shirts"));
    System.out.println("Hats: " + bd_map.get("Hats"));
    System.out.println("Shoes: " + bd_map.get("Shoes"));
}
```

However, Java 8 makes this much easier and less error-prone with the `merge()` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, BigDecimal> bd_map = new HashMap<>();

    bd_map.merge("Shirts", new BigDecimal("5.99"), BigDecimal::add);
    bd_map.merge("Shirts", new BigDecimal("4.50"), BigDecimal::add);
    bd_map.merge("Shoes", new BigDecimal("15.99"), BigDecimal::add);
    bd_map.merge("Hats", new BigDecimal("8.00"), BigDecimal::add);
    bd_map.merge("Shirts", new BigDecimal("8.99"), BigDecimal::add);
    bd_map.merge("Shoes", new BigDecimal("22.00"), BigDecimal::add);
    bd_map.merge("Hats", new BigDecimal("7.00"), BigDecimal::add);

    System.out.println("Shirts: " + bd_map.get("Shirts"));
    System.out.println("Hats: " + bd_map.get("Hats"));
    System.out.println("Shoes: " + bd_map.get("Shoes"));
}
```

Advantages to the Java 8 approach:

1. No need to initialize the original value (`BigDecimal.ZERO`)
2. No need to refer to the old value (`HashMap::get`) and add it
3. It's clean